# get sum of columns in next column sql

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2014, rollup

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr><th>Pcode</th><th>TCode</th><th>TName</th><th>CCode</th><th>Rate</th><th>Total=sum(rates of all PCodes)</th></tr>
  <b><tr><td>12345</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>12</td><td>2000</td><td>8000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>12345</td><td>201</td><td>200</td><td>12</td><td>1000</td><td>8000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>12345</td><td>202</td><td>200</td><td>12</td><td>2000</td><td>8000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>12345</td><td>205</td><td>200</td><td>12</td><td>3000</td><td>8000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>12346</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>12</td><td>4000</td><td>32000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>12346</td><td>204</td><td>200</td><td>12</td><td>5000</td><td>32000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>12346</td><td>208</td><td>200</td><td>12</td><td>5000</td><td>32000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>12346</td><td>1235</td><td>200</td><td>12</td><td>3000</td><td>32000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>12346</td><td>12</td><td>200</td><td>12</td><td>7000</td><td>32000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>12346</td><td>100</td><td>200</td><td>12</td><td>8000</td><td>32000</td></tr>
  
</table>
<p>I have a table with Pcode, Tcode, TName, CCode, Rate. Need to find the sum under Pcode as Total in next column</p>
```

I want this table column '(Total)' to be fetched along with all columns in the below table(SQL).

I have tried ROLLUP and group by no solution yet.

the total to be group by Pcode and get that sum to the next column.

TIA,

Comment: Where is the table? Please also provide sample data and the desired output corresponding to that sample data.

Comment: sorry forgot to add html code

Comment: You should also include the query that you tried.  Take a look at this: http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

```
With your_table_CTE as (
    select C.x,A.y,B.x from DFG inner join A, inner join B, inner join C
)

select a.pcode, a.TCode, a.TName, a.CCode, a.Rate, b.Total
from your_table_CTE a
join (
  select pcode, sum(rate) as Total
  from your_table_CTE
  group by pcode
) b
on a.pcode = b.pcode
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but you need to also use `your_table` in the subquery and alias `sum(rate)` as `Total` in order for it to work.

Comment: your_table is not just a table its a select * from four different tables with inner joins.  `your_table = select C.x,A.y,B.x from DFG inner join A, inner join B, inner join C` so `your_table` is a query not a table.

Comment: You can use a Common Table Expression with your query first then..  `with your_table_CTE as (select C.x,A.y,B.x from DFG inner join A, inner join B, inner join C)  select ...`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use `GROUP BY`.  This solution uses a Common Table Expression (replace `tempTable` with the name of your table):

```
;WITH TotalByPCode (PCode, Total) AS (
    SELECT PCode, SUM(Rate) FROM tempTable GROUP BY PCode
    )

SELECT R.PCode, R.TCode, R.TName, R.CCode, R.Rate, T.Total
FROM tempTable R JOIN TotalByPCode T ON R.PCode = T.PCode
;
```